# Set CoreData NSManagedObjectContext thread priority

Tags: ios, multithreading, core-data, grand-central-dispatch

At least since iOS 9 the only non-deprecated thread concurrency type for Core Data operations, not running in the main thread, is NSPrivateQueueConcurrencyType.
My problem is now, that I want to change the thread priority for that, like this:

```
...:(int) neededPriority {
  _queue = dispatch_queue_create("Worker", DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL);
  dispatch_set_target_queue(_queue,
    dispatch_get_global_queue(neededPriority, 0));
```

Sometimes I need a high priority, sometimes a low. But when I call `[_privateContext performBlock:...]` I can't pass a parameter with the needed priority, nor has the context any property to set its thread priority.
Therefore my question: is there any way to put the context queue into a certain thread priority?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`NSManagedObjectContext` instances are assigned queues, not threads.  The queue associated with the `performBlock` routine may be run an arbitrary background thread, so you can't assign a general priority to a context.

Instead, from inside the `performBlock` block, you can call `NSThread.setThreadPriority` to change the priority of the thread that is handling that block.

You might want to save the thread's priority before changing it, and reset it at the end of the block.

Comment: If you use `performBlockAndWait:` while on the main thread, the queue will run the block on the main thread. So any `NSThread` calls would apply to the main thread.

Comment: Thanks, a quick test with `NSLog(@"Old thread priority: %f", [NSThread threadPriority]);
        if (![NSThread setThreadPriority:0.1]) {
            NSLog(@"Couldn't set priority!");
        } else {
            NSLog(@"New thread priority: %f", [NSThread threadPriority]);
        }` showed that it seems to work.

Comment: just an additional info: this does only work on the device, not simulator